# In Excel, how to use data validation on two columns at the same time

Tags: excel, validation

I have an excel sheet with client data, one row per client. I need to designate each client as "P" (Primary) or "S" (Secondary). There is a separate P and S column. Each client cannot be both and must be designated one or the other. I already have data validation on each column restricting entry to either "P" or "S". I would like to use Data Validation to catch data entry mistakes, either both P and S marked, or both blank. In the table below, row 1 and 2 are good, row 3 and 4 need to be flagged.

```
 Primary  Secondary
1    P    
2         S
3
4    P    S
```

I can't combine the two columns into one Primary/Secondary column, since other formulas rely on them being separate. I could add a check column using the code below, but I am giving the spreadsheet to someone else to use and would like to avoid adding complexity.

```
=IF(AND(A2="P",B2="S")=TRUE,"duplicate",IF(AND(A2<>"P",B2<>"S")=TRUE,"empty",""))
```

Thanks.

Comment: how about `Conditional Formatting` to highlight the cases where both are blank or filled? It would be impossible to Validate them against each other without a circular reference. You could also use `Worksheet_Change` event with VBA code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend that you use conditional formatting to highlight rows where both columns are blank. This reduces complexity by forcing the user to acknowledge an error and deal with it, rather than trying to eliminate the possibility of having an error in the first place. Usually, in my opinion, forcing the user to deal with the error is cleaner than trying to be completely foolproof [especially in an internal setting, where you have a closer-than-usual client relationship].

To do this, select columns B & C, and type the following formula in a new Conditional Formatting rule [Home Ribbon > Styles > Conditional Formatting]:

```
=AND(NOT(ISBLANK($A1)),ISBLANK($B1),ISBLANK($C1))
```

This checks to see that: (1) A isn't blank [ie: this isn't an empty row] for a particular row, (2) B is blank for that row, and (c) C is blank for that row. Note that I have used $'s for the column letters but not the row numbers, because we want the rows to stay relative to each row of the rule, but we always want the columns to be A, B & C.

Then make the rule highlight those cells yellow. This provides a clear warning that those rows are not yet complete.

Comment: Thanks, I had not considered Conditional Formatting. In addition to your suggestion, I also added `=AND(NOT(ISBLANK($A1)),NOT(ISBLANK($B1)),NOT(ISBLANK($C1))) ` to cover the case when both columns are filled. Conditional formatting is definitely a gentler way of drawing the user's attention to mistakes.